# Como actualizo la actividad utilizando un dialogo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, activity

tengo una situación con esta parte de mi código, tengo mi actividad en la cual se realiza una operación matemática, al momento de que se ingresa el resultado quiero que salga una ventana de diálogo indicando que el resultado es correcto o incorrecto, que se presiona un botón en la ventana de diálogo y se reinicie la actividad para que muestre otra operación.

La cuestión es que al momento de que se ingresa la respuesta lanza el diálogo pero lo pasa, no deja que se presiona el botón y solamente reinicia la actividad.
espero me pueda ayudar, gracias.

```
 public void Resta (View view){
    reproduce.play(sonido, 1,1, 1, 0, 0);

    res=n1-n2;
    String Respuesta=Result.getText().toString();
    int Resp=Integer.parseInt(Respuesta);

   if (Resp==res){
       c=0;
        new Pop(contexto,c);

    }
    else {
        c=-1;
       new Pop(contexto,c);
    }
    //finish();
   startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

este es el dialogo

```
public class Pop {

public Pop(final Context contexto, int n) {

    final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(contexto);
    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    if (n == 0) {
        dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.win);

        ImageView ok = (ImageView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Ok);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogo.dismiss();
            }
        });


    } else {
        dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.lose);

        ImageView ok = (ImageView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Ok2);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialogo.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    dialogo.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

tome tu codigo e hice pequenos cambios

```
public class MainDialog {

public MainDialog(final Context contexto, int n) {

    final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(contexto);
    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // uno solo layout para el dialogo, el contenido es el que cambia
    ImageView ok1 = dialogo.findViewById(R.id.image_ok_1); 
    ImageView ok2 = dialogo.findViewById(R.id.image_ok_2);

    if (n == 0) {
        ok1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ok1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogo.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        ok2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ok2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogo.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    dialogo.show();
}
}
```

El layout del dialo es el siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_ok_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_star_1"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_ok_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_star_2"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

No ncesitas crear un layout para cada respuesta, solo necesitas cambiar el contenido, te sugiero no limpiar el activity asi `startActivity(getIntent());` limpia solo lo que sea necesario, si no el usuario vera eso como que alguien presiono F5 en una pagina web no es buena experiencia de usuario.

Saludos!

Comment: bien, si me sirve, para ahorrarme un activity, pero si quito el startActivity, no se reinicia la actividad, y necesito que se reinicie para que pueda generarse una nueva operación. gracias

Comment: No necesitas reiniciar un activity, no es algo común eso, si necesitas cargar nuevo contenido debes limpiar lo que tienes y cargar lo nuevo, otra opción es cargar eso en un fragment, como dije anteriormente eso no es como presionar F5